# Is it possible to only parse one argument group's parameters with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group1 = parser.add_argument_group('group1')
group1.add_argument('--test1', help="test1")

group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group2')
group2.add_argument('--test2', help="test2")

group1_args = group1.parse_args()
group2_args = group2.parse_args()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    group1_args = group1.parse_args()
AttributeError: '_ArgumentGroup' object has no attribute 'parse_args'
```

Is there a way to only get the arguments for one argument group?

Comment: How would you know which group's arguments were present before parsing all of them?

Comment: Maybe just create separate ArgumentParser instances?

Comment: @larsks could you elaborate more? Would it be leveraging `parse_known_args()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As your error message indicates, an ArgumentGroup is not a parser, specifically it doesn't have the `parse_args` method.

ArgumentParser objects and ArgumentGroup objects share a base ArgumentContainer class that gives them methods like `add_argument`.  But an ArgumentParser has a lot of additional code.  An ArgumentGroup is really just an aid in formatting the `help`.  It does not affect parsing in any way.

To add confusion, a `mutually_exclusive_group` subclasses `ArgumentGroup`, but affects only the `usage` part of the `help`, and affects parsing by raising an error message.

If you elaborate on why you want to do this, we could come up with some alternatives that might work.  For example there is a `parents` mechanism, that lets you `insert` one `parser` into another.  Or `subparsers` that pass parsing control to a subparsers via 'command' arguments.

---

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents

Defining each group in its own `parent` parser, would let you control both the help display, and parsing.  Only problem with parents is that you have to use `help=False` at some level to prevent the duplication of the `-h` option.

You may also need to use `parse_known_args` so the 'group' parser does not complain about arguments that it does not recognize.

---

Here's a way of displaying all the `args` entries, grouped by argument group.  I'm including the 2 default groups, optionals and positionals.  It does make use of 'private' attributes of the parser.  There's a bit of risk in doing so, but this isn't the kind of thing that is likely to be changed in future patches.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group1 = parser.add_argument_group('group1')
group1.add_argument('--test1', help="test1")

group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group2')
group2.add_argument('--test2', help="test2")

args = parser.parse_args('--test1 one --test2 two'.split())

print([g.title for g in parser._action_groups])  # all group titles
print(group1._group_actions)  # arguments/actions of `group1`
print([a.dest for a in group2._group_actions]) # actions for group2

for group in parser._action_groups:
    group_dict={a.dest:getattr(args,a.dest,None) for a in group._group_actions}
    print(group.title, argparse.Namespace(**group_dict))
```

producing

```
1513:~/mypy$ python stack31519997.py 
['positional arguments', 'optional arguments', 'group1', 'group2']
[_StoreAction(option_strings=['--test1'], dest='test1', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='test1', metavar=None)]
['test2']
('positional arguments', Namespace())
('optional arguments', Namespace(help=None))
('group1', Namespace(test1='one'))
('group2', Namespace(test2='two'))
```

If could be more convenient to work with `vars(args)`, the dictionary version.  `argparse.Namespace(**adict)` recreates a namespace from a dictionary.

Of coarse you make your own `dest` lists, `['test1']` and `['test2']`.

Comment: This is purely for readability. I have two category of parameters, and would like to represent that clearly when using them.

Comment: I also called `parser.parse_args()` before `group1.parse_args()` and `group2.parse_args()` so that `-h` will show the help for both sets of parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you might be more interested in a way dividing `args=parser.parse_args()` into 2 or more subsets, without parsing afresh.

Comment: Yes! I just realized a while ago. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I've added a way of collecting namespace attributes by group(s).