# Parse multiple subcommands in python simultaneously or other way to group parsed arguments

Tags: python, argparse, subcommand

I am converting Bash shell installer utility to Python 2.7 and need to implement complex CLI so I am able to parse tens of parameters (potentially up to ~150). These are names of Puppet class variables in addition to a dozen of generic deployment options, which where available in shell version.

However after I have started to add more variables I faced are several challenges:
1. I need to group parameters into separate dictionaries so deployment options are separated from Puppet variables. If they are thrown into the same bucket, then I will have to write some logic to sort them, potentially renaming parameters and then dictionary merges will not be trivial.
2. There might be variables with the same name but belonging to different Puppet class, so I thought subcommands would allow me to filter what goes where and avoiding name collisions.

At the momment I have implemented parameter parsing via simply adding multiple parsers:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='deployment parameters.')
env_select = parser.add_argument_group(None, 'Environment selection')
env_select.add_argument('-c', '--client_id',  help='Client name to use.')
env_select.add_argument('-e', '--environment', help='Environment name to use.')
setup_type = parser.add_argument_group(None, 'What kind of setup should be done:')
setup_type.add_argument('-i', '--install', choices=ANSWERS, metavar='', action=StoreBool, help='Yy/Nn Do normal install and configuration')
# MORE setup options
...
args, unk = parser.parse_known_args()
config['deploy_cfg'].update(args.__dict__)

pup_class1_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=None)
pup_class1 = pup_class1_parser.add_argument_group(None, 'Puppet variables')
pup_class1.add_argument('--ad_domain', help='AD/LDAP domain name.')
pup_class1.add_argument('--ad_host', help='AD/LDAP server name.')
# Rest of the parameters

args, unk = pup_class1_parser.parse_known_args()
config['pup_class1'] = dict({})
config['pup_class1'].update(args.__dict__)
# Same for class2, class3 and so on.
```

The problem with this approach that it does not solve issue 2. Also first parser consumes "-h" option and rest of parameters are not shown in help.

I have tried to use [example selected as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448200/how-to-parse-multiple-sub-commands-using-python-argparse) but I was not able to use both commands at once.

```
## This function takes the 'extra' attribute from global namespace and re-parses it to create separate namespaces for all other chained commands.
def parse_extra (parser, namespace):
  namespaces = []
  extra = namespace.extra
  while extra:
    n = parser.parse_args(extra)
    extra = n.extra
    namespaces.append(n)

  return namespaces

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

argparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = argparser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')

parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('command_a', help = "command_a help")
## Setup options for parser_a
parser_a.add_argument('--opt_a1', help='option a1')
parser_a.add_argument('--opt_a2', help='option a2')

parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('command_b', help = "command_b help")
## Setup options for parser_a
parser_b.add_argument('--opt_b1', help='option b1')
parser_b.add_argument('--opt_b2', help='option b2')


## Add nargs="*" for zero or more other commands
argparser.add_argument('extra', nargs = "*", help = 'Other commands')

namespace = argparser.parse_args()
pp.pprint(namespace)
extra_namespaces = parse_extra( argparser, namespace )
pp.pprint(extra_namespaces)
```

Results me in:

```
$ python argtest.py command_b --opt_b1 b1 --opt_b2 b2 command_a --opt_a1 a1
usage: argtest.py [-h] {command_a,command_b} ... [extra [extra ...]]
argtest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: command_a --opt_a1 a1
```

The same result was when I tried to define parent with two child parsers.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Can I somehow use parser.add_argument_group for argument parsing or is it just for the grouping in help print out? It would solve issue 1 without missing help side effect. Passing it as `parse_known_args(namespace=argument_group)` (if I correctly recall my experiments) gets all the variables (thats ok) but also gets all Python object stuff in resulting dict (that's bad for hieradata YAML)
2. What I am missing in the second example to allow to use multiple subcommands? Or is that impossible with argparse?
3. Any other suggestion to group command line variables? I have looked at Click, but did not find any advantages over standard argparse for my task.

Note: I am sysadmin, not a programmer so be gently on me for the non object style coding. :)

Thank you

**RESOLVED** 
Argument grouping solved via the answer suggested by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj).

```
import argparse
import pprint
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group_list = ['group1', 'group2']

group1 = parser.add_argument_group('group1')
group1.add_argument('--test11', help="test11")
group1.add_argument('--test12', help="test12")

group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group2')
group2.add_argument('--test21', help="test21")
group2.add_argument('--test22', help="test22")

args = parser.parse_args()
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

d = dict({})

for group in parser._action_groups:
    if group.title in group_list:
        d[group.title]={a.dest:getattr(args,a.dest,None) for a in group._group_actions}

print "Parsed arguments"
pp.pprint(d)
```

This gets me desired result for the issue No.1. until I will have multiple parameters with the same name. Solution may look ugly, but at least it works as expected.

```
python argtest4.py --test22 aa  --test11 yy11 --test21 aaa21
Parsed arguments
{   'group1': {   'test11': 'yy11', 'test12': None},
    'group2': {   'test21': 'aaa21', 'test22': 'aa'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too complicated to understand and respond to in one try.  But I'll throw out some preliminary ideas.

Yes, `argument_groups` are just a way of grouping arguments in the help.  They have no effect on parsing.

Another recent SO asked about parsing groups of arguments:

[Is it possible to only parse one argument group's parameters with argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519997/is-it-possible-to-only-parse-one-argument-groups-parameters-with-argparse)

That poster initially wanted to use a group as a parser, but the `argparse` class structure does not allow that.  `argparse` is written in object style.  `parser=ArguementParser...` creates one class of object, `parser.add_arguement...` creates another, `add_argument_group...` yet another.  You customize it by subclassing `ArgumentParser` or `HelpFormatter` or `Action` classes, etc.

I mentioned a `parents` mechanism.  You define one or more parent parsers, and use those to populate your 'main' parser.  They could be run indepdently (with parse_known_args), while the 'main' is used to handle help.

We also discussed grouping the arguments after parsing.  A `namespace` is a simple object, in which each argument is an attribute.  It can also be converted to a dictionary.  It is easy to pull groups of items from a dictionary.

There have SO questions about using multiple subparsers.  That's an awkward proposition.  Possible, but not easy.  Subparsers are like issueing a command to a system program.  You generally issue one command per call.  You don't nest them or issue sequences.  You let shell piping and scripts handle multiple actions.

`IPython` uses `argparse` to parse its inputs.  It traps help first, and issues its own message.  Most arguments come from config files, so it is possible to set values with default configs, custom configs and in the commandline.  It's an example of naming a very large set of arguments.

Subparsers let you use the same argument name, but without being able to invoke multiple subparsers in one call that doesn't help much.  And even if you could invoke several subparsers, they would still put the arguments in the same namespace.  Also `argparse` tries to handle flaged arguments in an order independent manner.  So a `--foo` at the end of the command line gets parsed the same as though it were at the start.

There was SO question where we discussed using argument names ('dest') like `'group1.argument1'`, and I've even discussed using nested namespaces.  I could look those up if it would help.

---

Another thought - load `sys.argv` and partition it before passing it to one or more parsers.   You could split it on some key word, or on prefixes etc.

Comment: Thanks. Links provided usefull answer for the challenge no.1. Now I am able to group options and move them to separate dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

If you have so many arguments this seems like a design issue. It seems very unmanageable. Can you not implement this using a configuration file that has reasonable set of defaults? Or defaults in the code with a reasonable (i.e. SMALL) number of arguments in the command line, and allow everything or everything else to be overridden with parameters in a 'key:value' configuration file? I can't imagine having to use a CLI with the number of variables you are proposing.

Comment: Well, I ALREADY do have config files and they are successfully used. The idea is to have an ability to override those values from CLI. Most likely there will be need to override 10-15 parameters, but selection for those 10-15 may be from whole set of possible configuration values. Just for the reference full product deployment is 15-17 hosts, which uses web service, 2 different DB services, 2 virtualization backends and is implemented in 5 programming languages. It may be I have missed something.

Comment: How about a parameter letting you choose which config file to use, and then reduce the over rideable parms to the highest likelihood ones for changes.

Comment: As I said, I already do have options for config file. In fact there were 3 of them (now 2) - file with defaults and config file with overrides/environment specific variables, depending on environment. However multiple deployments can be done, linked to the same environment and they can have several, or dozens different parameters to be overriden. Its a complex system, sometimes too complex :D