# Python argparse : How can I get Namespace objects for argument groups separately?

Tags: python, argparse

I have some command line arguments categorized in groups as follows:

```
cmdParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
cmdParser.add_argument('mainArg')

groupOne = cmdParser.add_argument_group('group one')
groupOne.add_argument('-optA')
groupOne.add_argument('-optB')

groupTwo = cmdParser.add_argument_group('group two')
groupTwo.add_argument('-optC')
groupTwo.add_argument('-optD')
```

How can I parse the above, such that I end up with three different Namespace objects?

```
global_args - containing all the arguments not part of any group
groupOne_args - containing all the arguments in groupOne
groupTwo_args - containing all the arguments in groupTwo
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think argparse has that feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group1 = parser.add_argument_group('group1')
group1.add_argument('--test1', help="test1")

group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group2')
group2.add_argument('--test2', help="test2")

args = parser.parse_args('--test1 one --test2 two'.split())

arg_groups={}

for group in parser._action_groups:
    group_dict={a.dest:getattr(args,a.dest,None) for a in group._group_actions}
    arg_groups[group.title]=argparse.Namespace(**group_dict)
```

This will give you the normal args, plus dictionary arg_groups containing namespaces for each of the added groups.

(Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519997/is-it-possible-to-only-parse-one-argument-groups-parameters-with-argparse))

Answer (score 5):

Nothing in `argparse` is designed to do that.

For what it's worth, the `parser` starts off with two argument groups, one that displays as `positionals` and the other as `optionals` (I forget the exact titles).  So in your example there will actually be 4 groups.

The parser only uses argument groups when formatting the help.  For parsing all arguments are put in a master `parser._actions` list.  And during parsing the parser only passes around one namespace object.

You could define separate parsers, with different sets of arguments, and call each with `parse_known_args`.  That works better with `optionals` (flagged) arguments than with `positionals`.  And it fragments your help.

I have explored in other SO questions a novel `Namespace` class that could nest values based on some sort of dotted `dest` (names like `group1.optA`, `group2.optC`, etc).  I don't recall whether I had to customize the `Action` classes or not.

The basic point is that when saving a value to the namespace, a parser, or actually a `Action` (argument) object does:

```
setattr(namespace, dest, value)
```

That (and getattr/hasattr) is all that the parser expects of the `namespace`.  The default `Namespace` class is simple, little more than a plain `object` subclass.  But it could be more elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation. I ended up manually grouping the Namespace attributes as I needed them. It would be a good addition to argparse if it could allow user to retrieve options by group name (i.e. use 'group' concept for more than just displaying help screen)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for this for a very long time,
And I think I finally got it.
So I will just put it here...

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def _parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-1', '--flag-1', action='store_true', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-2', '--flag-2', action='store_true', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-3', '--flag-3', action='store_true', default=False)

    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    print(f"args        : {args}")
    print(f"unknown     : {unknown}")

    hidden = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    hidden.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', default=False)
    hidden_args = hidden.parse_args(unknown)
    print(f"hidden_args : {hidden_args}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _parse_args()
```

as a result:
show help:

```
ubuntu → playAround $ ./test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-1] [-2] [-3]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -1, --flag-1
  -2, --flag-2
  -3, --flag-3
```

With debug flag:

```
ubuntu → playAround $ ./test.py -d
args        : Namespace(flag_1=False, flag_2=False, flag_3=False)
unknown     : ['-d']
hidden_args : Namespace(debug=True)
```

with flags 1 and 2:

```
ubuntu → playAround $ ./test.py -12
args        : Namespace(flag_1=True, flag_2=True, flag_3=False)
unknown     : []
hidden_args : Namespace(debug=False)
```

with flags 1 and 2 and debug:

```
ubuntu → playAround $ ./test.py -12 -d
args        : Namespace(flag_1=True, flag_2=True, flag_3=False)
unknown     : ['-d']
hidden_args : Namespace(debug=True)
```

The only thing you can't do with this approch is to pass the debug short flag along side to the other short flags:

```
ubuntu → playAround $ ./test.py -12d
usage: test.py [-h] [-1] [-2] [-3]
test.py: error: argument -2/--flag-2: ignored explicit argument 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method that calls the `parse_known_args()` method after each group is defined to get the names for those arguments separately.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('mainArg')
global_names = set(vars(parser.parse_known_args()[0]).keys())

group1 = parser.add_argument_group('group 1')
group1.add_argument('-optA')
group1.add_argument('-optB')
group1_names = set(vars(parser.parse_known_args()[0]).keys()) - global_names

group2 = parser.add_argument_group('group 2')
group2.add_argument('-optC')
group2.add_argument('-optD')
group2_names = set(vars(parser.parse_known_args()[0]).keys()) - global_names - group1_names

args = parser.parse_args()
global_args = argparse.Namespace(**dict((k, v) for k, v in vars(args).items() if k in global_names))
group1_args = argparse.Namespace(**dict((k, v) for k, v in vars(args).items() if k in group1_names))
group2_args = argparse.Namespace(**dict((k, v) for k, v in vars(args).items() if k in group2_names))

print(global_args)
print(group1_args)
print(group2_args)
```

E.g. `python args.py hi -optA fooA -optB fooB -optC fooC -optD fooD` will output:

> Namespace(mainArg='hi')
> Namespace(optA='fooA', optB='fooB')
> Namespace(optC='fooC', optD='fooD')