# Getting a dictionary of dictionary from argparse

Tags: python, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a python file which looks something like this :

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument() 
etc...
args = parser.parse_args()

function_one(a=args.a, b=args.b)
function_two(c=args.c, d=args.d, e=args.e)
```

What I would like to have is the following

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser_one = parser.add_parser(name1) 
parser_one.add_argument('--a')

parser_two = parser.add_parser(name2)
parser_two.add_argument('--d')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

So that `args` would be something like a dictionary of dictionary and `args.name1` would be the usual `NameSpace`.

This would enable me to divide my parser into subparser, and call the functions with :

```
function_one(**vars(args.name1))
function_two(**vars(args.name2))
```

I am aware of the function `add_argument_group`, but this merges the arguments into one `NameSpace` after calling `parser_args`.

And `add_subparsers` is also not the solution as it is exclusive between subparsers.

Comment: There's nothing in `argparse` that does this.  Conceivably you could write custom `Action` or `Namespace` classes to do this, but I think it would be simpler to just do the grouping or split after parsing.  (there's at least on earlier SO question like this).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668227/argparse-subcommands-with-nested-namespaces; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884513/python-argparse-how-can-i-get-namespace-objects-for-argument-groups-separately

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution to my problem was there :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884513/python-argparse-how-can-i-get-namespace-objects-for-argument-groups-separately